# Simple Mailing-List (not Newsletter) for Joomla?

Tags: joomla, mailing-list

Is there a way I can make joomla do the following:

I have several mail accounts that should act as a discussion mailing-list. The administrator (and only the adminstrator) maintains a list of customer email adresses that belong a particular discussion group mail adress. Whenever a Mail is sent to e.g. specialinterestdiscussion(at)mydomain.com, the mail will automatically be forwarded to all customers that belong to that list. If the sender is part of that mailling-list it will not be forwarded to him again. The sender does not necessarily have to be part of the maintained list.

So basically it is a simle mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Joomla is a php based engine it is simply not not possible. Joomla itself can not run a service in the background which would be required for a mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a way - by integrating a Plugin that runs on site refreshes in the background and checks for mails.

I can recommend [Mailster](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/mailing-a-distribution-lists/14070) which is a free and Open Source mailing list component for Joomla. It does exactly the job you need it to do, from the feature list:

> - Usable with any POP3/IMAP email account
> - Recipients are managed by the admin in the backend
> - Users can (un)subscribe with frontend plugin (optional)
> - All Joomla users can be chosen as recipients, additional users can be
>     stored
> - Users can be organized in groups    Single users or whole groups can be
>     added as recipients of a mailing list
> - Replies to mailing list posts can be    forwarded to all recipients
> - Backend mail archive for browsing the    mails
> - Full attachment support
> - [... more...]

I am using Mailster on my own webpage with a GMail account and it works like a charm.

Comment: Wouldn't that require that someone visits the site? What if that doesn't happen too frequently? Mails will not be distributed until someone visites the site. ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a good fully integrated solution for this myself, but there is a basic MailMan integration that you could search for.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, Joomla itself can not run a service in the background.

But the way plugins like [Mailster](http://www.brandt-oss.com/products/mailster) or LazyBackup2 work enables a service-like behavior. If your site has not enough visits you have to take care of that. E.g. by using a cron job that simply opens the webpage via wget every X minutes.

I just started to use Mailster and contacted the developer regarding the same question and he responded with the cron job advice and also said that he plans to add a specific PHP file for cronjobs. When this will be ready you don't even need to have the plugin anymore while still being able to manage everything inside Joomla.